mysql group by issues
Struggling with group by.
I have this query so far
select people.name, people.id, 
group_concat('org.org_id') as org_ids
from people
inner join org on org.vendor= people.vendor and org.inst_id = people.inst_id
group by people.id, org.org_id

It's giving me Unknown column org.org_id on field list
People table



id
name
vendor
inst_id




1
Jorge
walmart
7


2
Pete
walmart
7


3
bert
amazon
12


4
Omar
amazon
2



Org table



org_id
vendor
inst_id




10
walmart
1


10
amazon
2


22
walmart
7


22
amazon
12


11
walmart
7


36
amazon
2



I'd like the results to be



name
id
org_id(s)




Jorge
1
22,11


Pete
2
22,11


bert
3
22


Omar
4
36,10




you want to group by the things that are not being aggregated ...

Why are you group-concating the string literal 'org.org_id'? Single-quotes make it a string, not a column identifier. But that wouldn't cause any error. Are you really using back-ticks?

Sample data must be provided as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO,  according to Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, paragraph 5.

It's giving me Unknown column org.org_id on field list Shown query on shown tables structures CANNOT result in shown error message.

If the real query that the OP is executing uses back-ticks, then it would generate the error because \org.org_id`needs to be`org`.`org_id``. That is, delimit the table alias and the column name separately.

select people.name, people.id, 
group_concat('org.org_id') as org_ids
from people
inner join org on org.vendor= people.vendor and org.inst_id = people.inst_id
group by people.id, people.name

edit after comments: I think the single quotes making the column a string must be your issue.
select people.name, people.id, 
group_concat( org.org_id ) as org_ids
from people
inner join org on org.vendor= people.vendor and org.inst_id = people.inst_id
group by people.id, people.name


I am still getting that unknown column error. If i comment out the group_concat, the query does work but i need the display org_ids column
